# Como guardar cadenas en una lista doblemente ligada

Tags: c++

Tengo un archivo file.txt

```
|i|Correo|Apellido|Nombre|
|-+------+--------+------|
|0|a@.mx |a       |a     |
|1|b@.mx |b       |b     |
|2|c@.mx |c       |c     |
```

el cual lo leo con la siguiente funcion

```
void readFILE()
{
    ifstream file;
    string line;
    file.open(path, ios::in);

    if(file.fail()) printf("Error reading\n");
    while(!file.eof())
    {
        getline(file, line);
        cout << line << endl;
    }
    file.close();
}
```

Tengo el problema de que no se me ocurre una manera de tomar cada cadena que leo como si fuera todo el renglon una cadena y guardarlo en una lista doblemente enlazada

ejemplo.

```
line[0] = "|i|Correo|Apellido|Nombre|"
line[2] = "|0|a@.mx |a       |a     |"
```

tomar cada string y guardarlo en:

```
struct node {
    string *data;
    struct node *next;
    struct node *prev;
    int size;
};

struct node* MakeNode(string *data)
{
    struct node* newnode = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    newnode->prev = newnode;
    newnode->data = data;
    newnode->next = newnode;
    newnode->size = 1;
    return newnode;
}

struct node* addEnd(struct node* tail, string *data)
{
    struct node* newnode = MakeNode(data);
    if(tail == NULL) return newnode;
    else
    {
        struct node* temp = tail->next;
        newnode->next = temp;
        newnode->prev = tail;
        tail->next = newnode;
        temp->prev = newnode;
        tail = newnode;
        return tail;
    }
}
```

Yo me lo imagino como sacar toda la linea del archivo en una cadena, despues esa cadena almacenarla en la data del nodo para despues hacer operaciones con los nodos como  ordenar

Comment: Cuando dices "tomar cada string", ¿Te refieres a cada campo de la línea que estás leyendo? ¿A guardar cada línea tal cual en la lista?

Comment: Ya estás leyendo cada línea en el `while` de `readFILE`, no entiendo qué es lo que te falta.